# How to specify EF relationships that require SQL cast?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have two legacy SQL tables:

```
Contact
  Id(uniqueidentifier, not null)

Foo
  GlobalId(nvarchar(50, null)
  EntityName(nvarchar(100, null)
```

The Foo.GlobalId column stores the ID from other tables in the DB, so to get at relevant data, we'd join tables like this:

```
select * from Foo
  inner join Contact on Foo.EnitityName = 'contact'
    and cast(Foo.Globalid as unqiqueidentifier) = Contact.Id
```

How do I express this relationship or cast the nvarchar to uniqueidentifier (or vice versa) using FluentAPI, or failing that, how can I perform the SQL cast() using LINQ?

```
public class Contact
{
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
}


public class ContactMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
  HasKey(t => t.Id);
  HasMany(c => c.Foos)
    .WithOptional(foo => foo.Contact)
    /* ??? */;
}

public class Foo
{
  public string GlobalId {get;set;}
  public Contact Contact {get;set}
}


public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
  Property(t => t.PsmsGlobalId).HasMaxLength(50);
  Property(t => t.PsmsEntityName).HasMaxLength(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework currently does not support SQL type casts. Creating a SQL view which performed the cast worked well for me.